# What is the probability of getting at least two 1's on 5 dice

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

If I want to calculate the probability of getting at least one "1" by rolling 5 fair six-sided dice, I know I have to compute the probability of **not** getting it, hence 5/6. Since the events are independent, the probability is

$$(\frac{5}{6})^5$$

or 0.4, the complementary of which is 0.6.

Now, how can I calculate the probability of getting *at least* two 1's, since the events are dependent?

Comment: Which events are dependent? The second event can be treated without referring to the first one, i.e. there is no need to refer to the law of total probability.

Comment: [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) should have all the information you need.  Find the probability of exactly two 1's, exactly three 1's, exactly four 1's, exactly five 1's, and adding.  Alternatively you can subtract away from one the probability of getting exactly zero or exactly one 1.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the probability of zero 1's rolling is $\binom{5}{0}(\frac{1}{6})^0(\frac{5}{6})^5= (\frac{5}{6})^5= \frac{3125}{7776} \color{red}{\approxeq} 0.401878\dots$ which is **not equal to** $0.4$.  You should be exact whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red2$ ones is $\binom{5}{\color\red2}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red2}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{5-\color\red2}$
- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red3$ ones is $\binom{5}{\color\red3}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red3}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{5-\color\red3}$
- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red4$ ones is $\binom{5}{\color\red4}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red4}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{5-\color\red4}$
- The probability of getting exactly $\color\red5$ ones is $\binom{5}{\color\red5}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red5}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{5-\color\red5}$

---

Hence the probability of getting at least $\color\green2$ ones on $\color\purple5$ dice is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=\color\green2}^{\color\purple5}\binom{\color\purple5}{n}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{\color\purple5-n}$$

Answer (score 2):

The probability of getting zero 1's is $(\frac{5}{6})^5=\frac{3125}{7776}$

There are 5 ways of getting one 1, so the probability is $5\times\frac{1}{6}\times(\frac{5}{6})^4$

You want the probability of neither of these events:

$$1-(\frac{5}{6})^5-(5\times\frac{1}{6}\times(\frac{5}{6})^4)=\frac{763}{3888}$$

Comment: I think you meant $3888$.

Comment: @barakmanos thanks. fixed.